# Can State of Decay's XBox controller buttons be mapped to keyboard and/or mouse?

Tags: pc, controllers, keyboard, state-of-decay

*State of Decay* is supposedly unsupported for keyboard and mouse. Most keyboard commands work, but I can't seem to find the d-pad button equivalents.

I'm here to ask if anyone knows of any way I can map Xbox 360 controller buttons to keyboard/mouse via some program or other means.

Comment: Are you using the early access beta? Full keyboard support is promised to be in the final version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

State of decay CAN be played with mouse and keyboard. All of the commands are mapped out, the game just acts as if you are playing with a controller. You must learn for yourself which button to press, but here is the list of keyboard controls, courtesy of halfbloodv on Youtube:
(

)

Mouse Controls
X / Y Axis Turns the Camera
Left Click = Attacks or Fires and when held down it activates Emote mode
Right Click = Activates Aim Weapon Mode / Surveys Area 
Middle Mouse Scroll / Up & Down Zoom for map / Changes Weapon / Cycles through inventory)

Keyboard Controls on Foot 
ESC = Brings up main Menu / Pause
TAB = Opens Character Sheet & Inventory also Selects Next Page within a sheet
W = Runs Ahead & Climbs Up Ladders
S = Runs Back & Climbs Down Ladders
A = Run Left
D = Run Right
E = Opens Doors interacts / search 
F = Uses an Item in your inventory / Throws firebombs e.t.c.
M = Opens Map / Closes Map (left click selects waypoint, mouse wheel /up/down zooms in-out)
R = Reload Weapon
T = Activate / Deactivate Torch
Left SHIFT = Sprints & Moves up & down ladders faster
Left CTRL = Sneaks (Hold for 1 second to activate / Deactivate)
Left CTRL = Whilst running can be used to slide)
Space = Jumps

Hold Left Mouse and Press F = Drops Bag/Sack

Door Control
...never thought id be writing a guide for opening and closing doors....
To open and close a door quietly, simply hold left CTRL and press E
To open a door quickly, simply hold left SHIFT and press E
To break a door open simply gather momentum , keep holding left SHIFT and press E

Searching and Salvaging...
To search an item of interest that's glowing white, simply press and hold the E key, once this is held down you will see the search has begun. You can speed up the search by keeping E held down and pressing left shift to begin searching faster, note this is nosier and may attract unwanted attention.

Once you have searched and you see your inventory on the left and the contents on the item you searched on the right, from here you can use WSAD to move to the selected item, then LEFT click to take and item, once clicked it should then move to your inventory on the left, if you want to put an item back, simply go to your inventory on the left side and RIGHT click to put it back.

You will also see this is a category view system and by default you are in ammo, simply press TAB inside here to take you to the next tab, weapons, first aid e.t.c....

If you want to radio help for whatever reason, simply press the E key on the item and then use LEFT click to activate.

Advanced Fighting Controls
Shift & E = Performs Silent Kill (you have to be crouching, quiet and behind the enemy for this to work) This combination can also finish off an enemy who is laying on the ground.

Hold down shift then press left mouse click performs stronger attack

To add suppressor to the gun, make sure it's in your inventory and selected by using the mouse wheel, then simply press F to add to your weapon. Note some guns need certain silencers / compatibility mode.

When laying on the ground and your being eaten to death and it says press A repeatable to get up, "calmly" hold left RIGHT mouse button down as if you are going to do an EMOTE and repeatable press SPACE for your life! (press it very quickly like you're playing an old 80's game)

Controlling Car 
Right Mouse Click = Open drivers door
W = Accelerate
S = Brakes & Reverse (when car has stopped it turns to reverse)
A & D = Left and Right
E = Enter / Exit Car
T = Activate/Deactivate Headlights on Car
Q = Sound Horn / Siren
Space = Hand Brake
Space = When reversing this acts as a brake
Note only the mouse moves Camera ((If your mouse is slow to move camera then you can change the speed within Windows by going to control panel / mouse))

When driving at speed, you can also jump out the car by pressing E

Answer (score 0):

You can install the [**Icon and Keyboard Mouse Mod**](http://forums.undeadlabs.com/showthread.php?35199-Icon-Keyboard-amp-Mouse-Mod) by Th3DEAD to change most of the Xbox 360 controller buttons shown in the screen to their PC mouse/keyboard keys default equivalents. This should make learning the mouse/keyboard keys easier. I've listed the [default mouse and keyboard keys in this answer here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/132560/4797) for reference, too.

---

#### Editing the default keybinds

You can edit the default keybinds of the game by extracting *GameData.pak* in the `State of Decay\Game\` folder and then editing *prototypeactionmap.xml* in the `State of Decay\Game\libs\config` folder.

You can either extract the GameData.pak yourself, or download [a ZIP file of the already extracted files here](http://www.mediafire.com/download/zitkcpy3yr9pt7j/GameData.zip).

#### Download the extracted files of GameData.pak

If you're going to download the [ZIP file of the already extracted files](http://www.mediafire.com/download/zitkcpy3yr9pt7j/GameData.zip), extract the zip to your `State of Decay\Game` folder.
Then go to the `State of Decay\Game` folder and rename "*gamedata.pak*" to "*gamedata-backup.pak*".

#### Extracting GameData.pak through QuickBMS GUI

If you're going to extract the files yourself, you are going to need an application called [QuickBMS GUI (download link)](http://www.mediafire.com/download/osgmiuzm4u3i9o3/QuickBMS.zip). Once it's downloaded, extract the two files to your desktop and install and launch Quick BMS.

<sup>Note: Extracting works for all PAK files.</sup>
At the top, click "Script File", then "Open" and select the script you extracted (*zip2.bms*).
Click "Archive File" at the top and click "Open Archive", select the PAK file you want to extract - "*gamedata.pak*", which is in your `State of Decay\Game` folder.
Click folders at the top and select "Output Folder", go to where you grabbed the "*gamedata.pak*" file (`State of Decay\Game`).
At the bottom, click "Extract".

Then go to your `State of Decay\Game` folder and rename "*gamedata.pak*" to "*gamedata-backup.pak*".

#### Editing Keybinds

Go to the `State of Decay\Game\libs\config` folder, there will be a file called "*prototypeactionmap.xml*" -  this is the file you want to edit with a text editor if you want to change keybindings.

Its pretty self explanatory, change the key to the new key you want and save.

<sup>Note: Editing the other file "*defaultprofile.xml*" will not do anything.</sup>

---

<sup>Source: [Undead Labs forums post, "How To: Change keybindings", by user thexshadow](http://forums.undeadlabs.com/showthread.php?33518-How-To-Change-keybindings-and-other-graphical-settings)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

While the game currently does not officially support using the keyboard and mouse, keyboard and mouse controls *do* work. However, only Xbox 360 controller buttons are shown in the game interface, and keyboard and mouse controls currently can't be configured through in-game settings. Editing the mouse and keyboard controls [requires extracting and editing the game's XML configuration files](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/132329/4797).

Since the game only shows Xbox 360 controller buttons in its interface and messages, and extracting and editing the XML configuration files may be tedious, I am including here the default keyboard and mouse controls.

You can also install the **[Icon and Keyboard Mouse Mod](http://forums.undeadlabs.com/showthread.php?35199-Icon-Keyboard-amp-Mouse-Mod)** by Th3DEAD to change most of the Xbox 360 controller buttons shown in the screen to their PC mouse/keyboard keys default equivalents. This should make learning the default mouse/keyboard keys easier.

### Default Mouse and Keyboard Controls

(Note: *The text in brackets [ ] are Xbox 360 controller equivalents.*)

#### Mouse

( <kbd>LMB</kbd>, <kbd>RMB</kbd> and <kbd>MMB</kbd> are left, right and middle mouse buttons, respectively)

- <kbd>LMB</kbd> – Attack/Fire, Take/Store Item in Storage, Set/Clear Waypoint in Map
- <kbd>RMB</kbd> – Aim weapon, Survey (hold key) [LT], Save and exit (in Menu) [B]
- <kbd>RMB</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> – Use weapon scope (doing this with an unscoped weapon will swap the camera between your right and left shoulder)
- <kbd>RMB</kbd> and keep hitting <kbd>SPACE</kbd> – when laying on the ground and you're being eaten to death and it says press [A] to get up
- <kbd>MMB</kbd> – Change Weapon, Map zoom, Inventory cycle

#### Keyboard

- <kbd>W</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> – Forward, Left, Back, Right
- <kbd>ESC</kbd> – Menu
- <kbd>TAB</kbd> – Show Inventory and character sheet, Next tab in Character Sheet
- <kbd>Left SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> – previous tab in Character Sheet
- <kbd>E</kbd> – Interact/talk with other survivors, Open, Search, Barricade (hold key), Destroy item in inventory [Y]
- <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> – Execute downed zombies, Faster but noisier search, Silent kill (while sneaking/crouching next to an unaware opponent) [LB + Y]
- <kbd>F</kbd> – Use item or throw item (if current selected item is throwable, e.g. Petrol Bomb) [RB], Add silencer from inventory, Sound vehicle horn
- <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> – Drop rucksack
- <kbd>Left SHIFT</kbd> – Sprint, Climb ladder up/down faster
- <kbd>Left CTRL</kbd> – Sneak/Crouch [B], shake off zombies when the [B] prompt pops up
- <kbd>Left ALT</kbd> – Radio assistance menu
  <sub>Note: This does not work for earlier versions of the game (before the [2013-09-26 update](http://steamcommunity.com/games/StateOfDecay/announcements/detail/1802854726278609980)). See the [answer in this question here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/131993/4797) for a keybind fix.</sub>
- <kbd>SPACE</kbd> – Jump, Climb over wall or obstacle
- <kbd>R</kbd> – Reload
- <kbd>Q</kbd> – Car horn, Equip item (Inventory) [X]
- <kbd>M</kbd> – Open map
- <kbd>T</kbd> – Toggle flashlight/torch on/off, Toggle car headlights on/off [RS]
- <kbd>Left SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>LMB</kbd> – Special abilities that require you to press [LB + X]  (e.g. Decapitate)

#### Emotes

- Disagree – <kbd>LMB</kbd> (hold down) + <kbd>Left CTRL</kbd>  [B]
- Agree – <kbd>LMB</kbd>  (hold down) + <kbd>Space</kbd>  [A]
- Taunt – <kbd>LMB</kbd>  (hold down) + <kbd>Q</kbd>  [X]
- Cheer – <kbd>LMB</kbd>  (hold down) + <kbd>E</kbd>  [Y]

#### Notes:

- Scoping: Aiming (RMB) and then pressing the Q key will allow you to Zoom scoped weapons. Doing this with an unscoped weapon will swap the camera between your right and left shoulder.
- Drop Kick! Hold Shift + Tap Spacebar. It's your friend! Spacebar can be fun for 'flying whacks' as well, so feel free to mix up your combat.
- "MASH B TO ESCAPE". IF you've been thoroughly trained in how to use your RMB as the B key in menus, it's time to forget that. It's your left CTRL that will allow you to shake off Ferals and zombies when the 'B' prompt pops up. Yes. B is "dodge" everywhere besides the menu.
- Dropping Rucksacks: Hold down the SHIFT key and tap F. This will allow you to drop your rucksack.
- If you haven't figured it out yet, you can use Shift + E to execute downed zombies. This isn't just for sneaking, but a very effective way of cutting down on numbers rapidly. Zombies don't die until you crush their heads, and this has a 100% chance (and fun animations). You are also immune to damage during the animation, I believe.
- When laying on the ground and your being eaten to death and it says press A repeatable to get up, "calmly" hold RIGHT mouse button down as if you are going to do an EMOTE and repeatable press SPACE for your life! (press it very quickly like you're playing an old 80's game)"

For those who have [unpacked the controls configuration file](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/132329/4797):

- Shift + CTRL does not work to perform a combat roll. If you remap the CTRL key to another button, such as "c", you will be able to combat roll. You will also be able to taunt.
- Toggling Fire Mode. This should be the Spacebar, but the config file is missing a keyboard="space" in the appropriate line. (Do a search for 'firemode' and look for the line with 'xi_a')
- Counter attacking seems to be bugged. With an appropriate fight skill, this should be enabled by following up a dodge (CTRL, or C if you've remapped) with a click from the <kbd>LMB</kbd> or Q key, although neither appear to function.

---

Sources:

- [Play State of Decay Early Access with a keyboard – Here’s the control list | incgamers.com](http://www.incgamers.com/2013/09/play-state-of-decay-early-access-with-a-keyboard-heres-the-control-list)
- [Your Guide to Unsupported Keyboard/Mouse Functionality | Undead Labs forums](http://forums.undeadlabs.com/showthread.php?33891-Your-Guide-to-Unsupported-Keyboard-Mouse-Functionality)
- Personal in-game experimentation